How do I deploy asp.net MVC web project in local network on Windows 10 computer?
I have created a web project on recent ASP.NET MVC .Net Core. It works fine on my computer. Now I'd like to publish it in local network on a computer that runs Windows 10 Pro.
I have started with this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-8.0
I have enabled IIS component, it shows some default page. I also installed .NET Core Hosting Bundle installer. Next I use Visual Studio: Right-Click on project , choose Publish , choose Target : Web Server (IIS) , next Web Deploy , and now I do not know what to enter in User name and Password fields of this window:

So, how do I configure deployment of ASP.NET Core MVC app to computer on local network? I'd like it to be available at address: http://local-pc/webappname/

You can just follow this tutorial https://dotnetblog.asphostportal.com/how-to-publish-asp-net-core-blazor-application-to-iis/. I follow this tips and it is working fine.

I used "publish to folder" option and then manually copied files. That solved question for me

TBH, that's how I've usually chosen to do it, unless we have CI/CD pipelines for the site.
